# Importing a specific module thats not part of my current Python 2.X version

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, web-hosting

My webhost where our website is runs Python 2.4 & the website uses the SQLite3 python module (which is only part of Python 2.5 & up). This means that I cant use the module SQLite3 because its not part of Python 2.4.

Is there a way for me to upload the python SQLite3 module myself & just import/refernce that in my script? Do you know how I would do this?

Usually I would just install Python25 on my  webhost home directory, but this webhost wont allow me to do this.

Is there any way I can just upload & import a specific module - coming from c++ it seems this must be possible right? Because in C++ I spend my whole life writting libraries & just importing specific parts of them & importing specific classes of a namespace & etc.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends about how much control your webhost gives you about the Python environment. For normal shared hosting, the runtime Python environment is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why would python be designed like this? Its crazy, it means that if you want to create any wrapper, library thats not coded in native python you have to install it, not just import it in? This seems like a major design flaw. Also why are most web hosts still using python 2.4(2005) & not even 2.6 or 2.7 it seems so stupid

Comment: That's not a question about how Python is designed but what your webhost installed and allows you to change. You must check with your webhost, if uploading and adding a module to the Python environment is allowed by him.

Comment: yeah its not allowed though, they seem very unhelpful just resaying the same line, "You have to take python 2.4 as it is, any other optimisations & u'll have to upgrade to VPS"

Comment: There you go :) But that's how the business of webhosting gos. If you want more control, rent a VPS and install everything you want. That's how I do it. **Edit:** Perhaps you should head over to Serverfault.com http://serverfault.com/questions/12655/cheap-vps

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'm in Australia using an Australian Web Host(they're expensive & terrible compared to US web host) what is the average price I would expect for a VPS from a US WebHost?